# Spawning Zombies inside buildings

Tags: zombicide

I have a couple of questions about the spawning of zombies inside opened buildings in Zombicide.

1) When an actor opens a door, should we draw a zombie card for every room of the building, or just one per building?

2) If the players begin the game inside a building, are there zombies in it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) One per room.

2) No.

Quoting rules summary:

> Opening the first door in a building (except the start area) generates Zombies in each zone. For each zone, draw a Zombie card and place them accordingly.

Comment: Failing to spawn zombies for **each room** when opening the first door of a building is one of the major causes of the game being too easy.

Answer (score 4):

From the [rule book](http://guillotinegames.com/dl/zombicide_rulebook_english.pdf) (page 8) under the **Opening a Door** heading, you draw one card for each room (aka Zone).

> Opening the first door of a building reveals all Zombies which are inside. Point to each Zone of the building, one after the other, drawing a Zombie card each time. Place the corresponding number of Zombies on the correct Zone (see Zombie's turn).

From the [FAQ](http://guillotinegames.com/dl/zomb_faq_1.0_EN.pdf) (page 1), no Zombies spawn in the starting building.

> **Q: Should I draw a Zombie card when opening the door of the building containing the Player starting area?**
>
> No.

Answer (score 0):

1) One Per Room

2) No

Keep in mind this only applies to the first time an area is revealed.  So if a player re-seals a door via the "Lock It Down" skill and you open it again later, you will not spawn more zombies.